# Is it possible to break a carbon dioxide molecule using electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, molecules

I'm no expert in physics, but I was just wondering if breaking apart $\rm CO_2$ into oxygen and carbon would be possible using certain electromagnetic wave?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodissociation

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but not that easy as freecharly says. As it is mad of one carbon and two oxigen atoms, the splitting process has more possible end products. The energetically preferred one is carbon monoxide and an oxygen atom (CO + O ). But researchers discover a new way to have (C + 02)...look for example this article: https://phys.org/news/2014-10-oxygen-molecules-carbon-dioxide.html ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can decompose $CO_2$ with electromagnetic waves (light). It is possible to [ionize carbon dioxide](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/inchi?ID=C124389&Mask=20) with ultra-violett light with a photon energy of about 13.78 eV. And, for sure, you can decompose the whole molecule into atoms with light of appropriate photon energies.

Comment: Oops, I forgot about the second bond. This is probably the more accurate answer.